# Formik prop shows error for input after reset

Tags: react-native, formik

I have 4 `TextInput` A,B,C and D. I am using Formik for form management. After my form is submitted, I am resetting the form, but the last `TextInput` still shows error.

Here is the code for my `TextInput`

```
<TextInput
      placeholder={placeholder}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoFocus={autoFocus}
      ref={inputRef}
      style={StyleSheet.flatten([
        styles.input,
        {
          borderColor:
            formikProps.touched[name] && formikProps.errors[name]
              ? '#FF0000'
              : '#FFF',
        },
      ])}
      onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange(name)}
      onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur(name)}
      value={formikProps.values[name]}
    />
```

Before I click on submit; suppose D `TextField` has focus, and now when I click submit after a successful submission of the form, the D `TextInput` though its `value` gets reset, the border is still red. I tried using `useRef` to remove focus using `ref.current.blur()` but that too does not work.

Comment: Are you setting autoFocus on all the 4 `TextInput` field? If Yes, then it is wrong as `autoFocus` is meant to highlight only 1 field (when a form is loaded, submitted or reset) initially and not all fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
       onSubmit={(values, {resetForm, setSubmitting}) => {
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            setTimeout(() => {
              setSubmitting(false);
              resetForm();
            }, 100);
          }}
```